# Schengen Visa multiple entries - Must every visit be made to the same main country?

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry

Lets say I have France Schengen visa (multiple entries short stay of total 90 days in 6 months). I understand that my first ever visit to Schengen zone has to be France as the main destination. My question is : If I happen to make subsequent visits to Schengen area (while my visa is still valid with regards to dates and total duration)  - is it required on every visit (second, third, etc.) that France be my main destination for the visit?

PS: I know that I can enter any Schengen country for my visit - but I am specifically asking if I can *totally avoid* visiting the issuing country on my subsequent visits? Will doing so be used against me if I apply for visa in future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**.  It's a Schengen visa, valid for the entire region, not just France.

What's more, they can't even track if you went to France or not, since there are no immigration controls within Schengen.  All they know is the airport you enter and leave from.

Of course, each time you enter Schengen, the immigration officer will most likely ask why you are visiting etc, and you will need to explain why -- but they're only interested in whether you can afford to visit and whether you are going to return home.