# Can I re-enter the Schengen zone on a multiple-entry visa, if not entering into the country that issued it?

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry, denmark, geneva

I am a non-EU national (with a non-EU passport) residing in the UK as a student. I applied for a single-entry Schengen visa for Denmark around 2 months ago. I was granted a multiple-entry visa that is valid for 6 months (visa Type C, duration of stay valid for 90 days).

I made my trip to Denmark and returned back to the UK (duration of stay in Denmark: one week). I would now like to travel through to my home country for Christmas, and stop to visit a friend in Geneva en route (for approximately five days).

Is it possible to use the recently-granted Schengen visa for this, especially as I do not plan to visit Denmark on this trip?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  Please see the linked question for more information.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24729/schengen-visa-multiple-entries-must-every-visit-be-made-to-the-same-main-count?rq=1 seems closer to being a duplicate